# В чем разница между словами: сакральный и сакраментальный?

Tags: семантика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слова совпадают только в одном значении, религиозно-обрядовом. Причем это значение книжное и судя по всему постепенно устаревает.

~1. САКРАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. [от лат. sacer - священный]. Книжн.
Связанный с религиозным обрядом; обрядовый, ритуальный. С. характер танцев.

~2. САКРАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое. [от лат. os sacrum - крестец] Спец.
Относящийся к крестцу; крестцовый. С. отдел позвоночника.

~~~~

САКРАМЕНТАЛЬНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -лен, -льна, -льно. [лат. sacramentalis]
~1. =Сакральный (1.С.). С-ое значение обряда. С-ые слова.
~2. Священный, заветный. С-ая книга. С-ая заповедь. Любовь к родине - с-ое чувство.
~3. Ставший обычным; традиционный. С-ая формула. С-ое начало любой конференции. < Сакраментально, нареч. Сакраментальность, -и; ж.

(Большой толковый словарь)